# Is it possible to read input non blocking in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to read input in a loop but not block, and execute some other code on every iteration. Is it possible in bash?

```
while true
do
#some code that runs every loop iteration
read line if pipe has it 
#some code that runs every loop iteration
done
```

Comment: Yes, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/173779/187122.

Comment: @Socowi, this is exactly what I needed!